# How to delete the cookie file of the user who terminated the session?

Tags: cookies

hello i am researching deleting the cookie on the server side.i saw this code but here it deletes all cookies.whereas the cookie file is not a physical file on the user's browser ? in this case all of them are deleted when a user logs out, how will it delete the cookie that belongs only to him ?

```
if (Request.Cookies["UserSettings"] != null) {

    HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie("UserSettings");
    //Here, we are setting the time to a previous time.
    //When the browser detect it next time, it will be deleted automatically.
    myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1d);
    Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);

}
```

I did the cookie creation but I could not find where the cookie is created